# Adding condition to Unique Constraint

Tags: postgresql

I currently have the following constraint on a table:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
            ADD CONSTRAINT unique_row UNIQUE (content_id, brand_id, language_id);
```

I want to add a condition to the constraint:  I want the constraint to work the same way, but with only a single row where is_archived is FALSE:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
         ADD CONSTRAINT unique_row UNIQUE (content_id, brand_id, language_id, !is_archived);
```

However, when I do this I get a syntax error.

If `is_archived = true` then multiple rows with the same combination of `content_id` and `brand_id` are allowed.   Basically multiple rows that are the same can be archived, but only one can be unarchived.

Comment: A partial index is likely the most efficient solution, but you may also be interested in: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/276505/how-to-enforce-a-column-value-on-duplicate-values-on-postgresql-using-constraint/276511#276511

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While Postgres doesn't allow a partially unique constraint, it does support a partial unique index:

```
create unique index unique_row on myTable(content_id, brand_id) where not is_archived;
```

See [Partial Indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) in the Postgres documentation.

This is effectively pretty much the same as a unique constraint, because such constraints are implemented with unique indexes anyway.

Comment: Index lacks an option to be mentioned in ON CONFLICT case where only unique keys are accepted.

Comment: @AlexDvoretsky You can! You have to specify the same `where` that the partial index has after the columns in the `on conflict` clause. eg `... on conflict(content_id, brand_id) where not is_archived do update ...`